# Polymorphic Relationships - Retrieving the owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a polymorphic relationship setup as follows:

```
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :user_industries
end

class UserIndustry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :industry_id, :industriable_id, :industriable_type
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :industriable, polymorphic: true
end

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :user_industries, as: :industriable   
end

class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :user_industries, as: :industriable   
end
```

I have a search feature and I'd like to fetch, for example, all Applicants that have a certain Industry. Does Rails provide a convenient way to do this, or do I have to write some methods myself?

Comment: so what do you got so far?

Comment: Ended up going with this in the Industry model:

def applicants
    Applicant.where('id in (?)', UserIndustry.where(:industriable_type => 'Applicant', :industry_id => self.id).pluck(:id))
  end

Don't know if it's the most elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment that you wrote i assume, that you want to write a `join` query like this (untested):

```
Applicant.joins(:user_industries).where('user_industries.industry_id' => self.id).pluck('applicants.id')
```